# If I add more than 15 checkboxes element in a field my form stops working

Tags: forms

I'm building a form and I need to include a 'checkboxes' field.

This is my code:

```
$form['page-options-' . $nid]['mondi-' . $nid] = array(
    '#title' => 'Mondi Azzurra',
    '#description' => 'Seleziona i mondi azzurra di interesse',
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $mondi
  );
}
```

The $form['page-options-' . $nid] field is a simple fieldset.

For some reason if I sobstitute this

```
'#options' => $mondi
```

with

```
'#options' => array_slice($mondi, 0, 15)
```

limiting the array to 15 elements it works but if I set it 25 stop working again..

Changin field type from checkcboxes to select [with #multiple attribute set to true] the form works.

This is my hook_form_submit()

```
function adv_sumbission_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  dsm($form_state);

  drupal_set_message('The form is submitted');
}
```

and this is all my hook_form()

```
function adv_sumbission_form($form, $form_state) {

  $form['pages'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset', 
    '#title' => t('Pagine'),
    '#weight' => 1
  );

  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'pagine_adv'));
    foreach($nodes as $nid => $value){

      $form['pages']['page-' . $nid] = array(
        '#title' => $value->title,
        '#type' => 'checkbox'
      );  

      $form['page-options-' . $nid] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
           ':input[name="page-' . $nid.'"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)
         ),),
        '#attributes' =>  array('class' => array('page-options'))
      );

      if( isset($value->field_mondi_azzurra[LANGUAGE_NONE]) 
        && count($value->field_mondi_azzurra[LANGUAGE_NONE]) > 1 ) {
      $mondi = array();

      foreach($value->field_mondi_azzurra[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $mondo){
        $term = taxonomy_term_load($mondo['tid']);
        $mondi['term-'.$term->tid] = htmlentities(t($term->name));
      }

      $form['page-options-' . $nid]['mondi-' . $nid] = array(
        '#title' => 'Mondi Azzurra',
        '#description' => 'Seleziona i mondi azzurra di interesse',
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#options' => array_slice($mondi, 0, 25),
        '#required' => FALSE,
     );
   }
} // end foreach $nodes

$form['submitform'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Invia richiesta'),
  '#weight' => 6
 );


  return $form;
}
```

I need to know why there is a kind of limit to the checkboxes I can add and how I can debug where the form elaboration stop not serving to my form_submit my form data.

Comment: "*The form in the page is correctly generated but there is something wrong when Drupal elaborate it.*" What do you mean by this?

Comment: What @Chapabu says: "something wrong" and "not working" are curse of IT world. Is it an error with JS console? Unexpected HTML output? No error and expected HTML but expected behaviour != observed? *What* you expected and *what* you observed?

Comment: @Shyghar Please provide updates by editing, not in comments. Comments may be deleted at any moment and no one will really care.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: The only difference appears to be in the type of array key, eg, integer in one and string in the other.  So, take a look at the logic in your `form_submit`. You could throw in a `$mondi['x-' . $term->tid] = htmlentities(t($term->name));` or something similar and see if that changes things.

Comment: Question updated!!

Comment: Ok, my array generation is ok. But how can I search the problem now? I finished my ideas T___T If I set field type to select il works.. There is a way to see where the code stop working? [the data validation works with all the elements in array but it seems like in the checkboxes values elaboration for the mymodule_form_submit it stop working..]

Comment: @Shyghar One way to debug the things is using the devel module, check if you getting all the options at the time of rendering.

Comment: Where and how? In the page I have the correct options. Something happened after the submission and I don't know where to put my debug code because my _form_submit is not reached.

Comment: @Shyghar What's _"my _form_submit"_ in this context? You haven't mentioned anything about that in your question. Can I recommend that you remove what you've already got in this question and start again? I think you've got too close to the code to realise that it's impossible for anyone reading this question to understand what you're attempting to do, and what the actual problem is. Make it very simple: _1. This is what I'm trying to do. 2. This is how I'm trying to do it (include only the **relevant** code, including function names/signatures/etc). 3. This is what doesn't work_